# Change last character of every word in a sentence to a capital using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was challenged to write some Ruby code that changes the last character of every word in a sentence into a capital. Such that the string:

```
"script to convert the last letter of every word to a capital"
```

becomes

```
"scripT tO converT thE lasT letteR oF everY worD tO A capitaL"
```

This is what I ended up using:

```
"script to convert the last letter of every word to a capital".split.map{|w|w<<w.slice!(-1).chr.upcase}.join' '
```

For those interested as to what is going on here is an explanation.

**split** will split the sentence up into an array, the default delimiter is a space and with Ruby you don't need to use brackets here.

**map** the array from `split` is passed to map which opens a block and process each word (w) in the array. the block **slice!**(s) off the last character of the word and converts it to a **chr** (a character not ASCII code) and then capitalises **upcase** it.  This character is now appended **<<** to the word which is missing the sliced last letter.  Finally the array of words is now **join** together with a **' '** to reform the sentence.

Comment: This won't work if there is punctuation in the sentence. Is that a requirement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here's a quick and dirty regex method that's sure to be broken in ways I haven't considered:

```
"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".gsub(/.\b/) { |m| m.upcase }
```

i.e. upcase the last character match before a word boundary.

Comment: This is actually better than the original because it doesn't fail for non-space word boundaries.

Comment: The only problem I can find with this is inter-word punctuation, like apostrophes in contractions (eg. "don't").

Comment: @mckeed Good call. I knew something was missing.

Comment: how would you modify this to include apostrophes?

Answer (score 5):

With rails `titleize` method you could:

```
str.reverse.titleize.reverse
```

Comment: brilliant! 
(i suppose that was the intent of the original question)

Comment: Cool I was trying to think of a way using reverse, shame that titleize isn't a Ruby command... but there weren't really any rules anyway.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt at covering all the punctuation issues with a regexp:

```
str = %("But we're street-smart," she said.)

str.gsub(/\w\W*(\s|$)/) {|m| m.upcase }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well i don't know Ruby but here is attempt in its cousin (Python), it's even a bit shorter:

```
' '.join(w[:-1]+w[-1].upper()for w in
"script to convert the last letter of every word to a capital".split())
```

But the approach with reverse-titleize-reverse is the real deal:

```
"script to convert the last letter of every word to a capital"[::-1].title()[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.reverse.split(/\b/).map(&:capitalize).join.reverse
```

However, it downcases all other letters...